# How can I validate OpenAPI's Schema Object

Tags: openapi, json-schema-validator

I'm using OpenAPI 3 Spec to document my APIs.

I want to automate my tests so instead if asserting whole payload I'd validate it against documentation.

But since OpenAPI is not a JSON Schema its Validation Spec won't work with OAS Schema Objects

Is there a OpenAPI Schema Object Validation Spec?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this link:

https://philsturgeon.uk/api/2018/04/13/openapi-and-json-schema-divergence-solved/

> My previous article explained the divergence between OpenAPI and JSON Schema (a.k.a the subset/superset/sideset problem), and promised solutions. One of those solutions is a tangible thing, which you can install right now! The other is now ready for tool vendors to start considering.
>
> To briefly recap: OpenAPI v3 declares it supports JSON Schema, but there are more caveats than I can ever remember to that.